# Anaconda navigator not opening

Tags: anaconda3

I installed anaconda navigator and when i clicked it, the cursor showed loading symbol and that's it it didn't open nor show any signs. I tried reinstalling it multiple times and also tried running it as administrator still no change

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!